# Extend an Screen options in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

i have several screens in stack navigator like below

```
   <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={TransitionScreenOptions}>
      <Stack.Screen
        options={stackoptions}
        name="videoScreen"
        component={videoScreen}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        options={stackoptions}
        name="registerScreen"
        component={SignUpScreen}
      />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

for all the screens i set options like below

```
const stackoptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  headerBackTitleVisible: false,
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "#000",
  },
  headerTintColor: "#fff",
  headerRight: () => {
    return (
      <Pressable
        style={{ paddingRight: 8 }}
        onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
      >
        <AntDesign name="menu-fold" size={30} color="white" />
      </Pressable>
    );
  },
});
```

Now , how can i override or add certain options to one of my screen , for example something like below , I want to modify only `headerTintColor` , whereas  remaining stackoptions should be used except headerTintColor.

```
  <Stack.Screen
             options={...stackoptions, headerTitle: "" }
            name="registerScreen"
            component={SignUpScreen}
          />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for all the screens i set options like below

This is unnecessary. You can specify common options in `screenOptions` and they'll be applied to all screens, it's not needed to repeat them for every screen. You can use spread operator to merge your `TransitionScreenOptions` with the others:

```js
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={({ navigation }) => ({
  ...TransitionScreenOptions,
  headerBackTitleVisible: false,
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "#000",
  },
  headerTintColor: "#fff",
  headerRight: () => {
    return (
      <Pressable
        style={{ paddingRight: 8 }}
        onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
      >
        <AntDesign name="menu-fold" size={30} color="white" />
      </Pressable>
    );
  },
})}>
```

You can just do this:

```js
options={{ headerTitle: "" }}
```

This will override the same option if it was specified in `screenOptions`

If you need to use the current structure, call the `stakOptions` function and pass the arguments before spreading it:

```js
options={args => ({
  ...stackoptions(args),
  headerTitle: ""
})}
```

Comment: Actually I have around 10 screens.. 5 have certain options , another 5 have certain options..

Comment: @Graciewilliams There's a Group component in 6.x pre-release to help with that. For 5.x I updated the answer with example code.